# Pass a lambda to a generic function

Tags: vb.net, generics, lambda

I would like to create a generic class that can be used to contain items from a database table

As follows

```
Public Class RowCache(Of t)
    Private items As New List(Of t)
    Public Sub AddItem(item As t)
        Me.items.Add(item)
    End Sub
    Public Function find(Filter As ?????) As t
        ????
    End Function
End Class


Public Class useit
    Public Sub test()
        Dim ob As New RowCache(Of teamrow)
        ob.find(func(rec) rec.teamcode)

        Dim ob2 As New RowCache(Of employeerow)
        ob2.find(func(rec) rec.employeeno)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is it possible to create the find method and if so how is it done

1. What goes in the parameter list
2. How do I use this in the find function

Comment: Are you wanting to use the `IQueryable.Where` method? Or..?

Comment: Please explain what `find` is supposed to *do*. For example, what should `find(func(rec) rec.teamcode)` return? The teamcodes of all rows? All fields of specific rows?

Comment: find should have included a condition to compare to function(rec) rec.teamcode = 1 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a lambda to the find function, which returns true if the item is found. You can combine this with Linq's SingleOrDefault to find the single item which is filtered.

```
Public Function find(filter As Func(Of t, Boolean)) As t
    Return Me.items.SingleOrDefault(filter)
End Function
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Dim result = ob.find(Function(rec) rec.teamcode = 1)
```